# Can the hydride ion act as a ligand?

Tags: ions, coordination-compounds, hydrogen

Hydride ion, as I know is a pretty powerful base, much stronger than hydroxide ion and cannot exist in an aqueous phase.

Can it act as a ligand in coordination compounds? Hydride ion has its electronic configuration as $\mathrm{1s^2}$ in a symmetrical *s* orbital so the tendency to donate a lone pair into a metal atom would be less. But can its high nucleophilicity allow it to bind to the metal atom despite the symmetry of its orbital?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples. For instance

- The common reducing agents LithAl, $\ce{LiAlH4}$, and sodium borohydride, $\ce{NaBH4}$ (last one you might argue about)
- $\ce{[ReH9]^{2-}}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_nonahydridorhenate
- Metal carbonyl hydrides, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_carbonyl_hydride
- More generally many organometallic compunds, e.g. $\ce{(C5H5)_2ReH}$

A quick google also shows up http://www.ilpi.com/organomet/hydride.html

Comment: Are these coordination compounds? I thought in LiAlH4 and others, the hydrogen was *covalently* bonded with the metal atom. Is it a dative bond that exists between them?

Comment: Does the model of the bonding matter? In $\ce{MnF6^{2-}}$ the best model is probably ionic while in $\ce{PtI6^{2-}}$ covalent is probably nearer to the truth, and then you have $\ce{{Cu(NH3)_4}^{2+}}$ where some kind of dative bond is the most intuitive model. But I think we'd all be happy to call them metal complexes, which are examples of coordination compounds.

Comment: I guess thats true

Comment: There’s also the nice case of pentacarbonyl iron which, when hydroxide ions are added, reacts to give $\ce{[Fe(CO)4(COOH)]-}$ which then rearranges and liberates $\ce{CO2}$ to give $\ce{[FeH(CO)4]-}$. This compound is Brønsted amphotheric: it can be protonated to give neutral $\ce{[FeH2(CO4)]}$ or deprotonated to give $\ce{[Fe(CO)4]^2-}$. I think it’s fascinating!